# Anti-up quark vs down quark

Tags: particle-physics, charge, antimatter, quarks, elementary-particles

I'm beginning to study some particle physics and as I understand, all particles have an antiparticle that is identical besides charge, which is inverted. Thus I understand that there is a difference between an anti-electron and a proton (or vice versa) but since (as far as I can tell) the up and down particles have the same mass, is the anti-up quark a down quark?

Comment: the antielectron has the mass of the electron, the antiproton the mass of the proton.  so it is also mass that differs . Also see this for masses of quarks  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html

Answer (score 5):

No. The anti-up has charge -2/3 and the down has charge -1/3. They do have different masses also.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number#Baryon_number_vs._quark_number

Answer (score 0):

The antiup quark has more charge than down quark. Also they can combine to form pion that has a negative charge.